# htaccess rewrite combining lines

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 3 rewrite lines in htaccess on a site and would like to know If I can combine them.

Here are the 3 lines:

```
RewriteRule ([0-9]+)-folder/  http://www.example.com/folder/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule folder/([0-9]+)-  http://www.example.com/folder/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule folder/(.*)/([0-9]+)-  http://www.example.com/folder/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Basicly, the top 2 lines would need to take effect BEFORE the 3rd line.  It is also possible that the top 2 lines need to take effect WITHOUT the 3rd line being used (when the 3rd line doesn't apply).

I think that sums it up.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Forgot to say... line 1 OR line 2 will apply.  Now both at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below rule for first two lines use second rule as it is,

```
RewriteRule ((([0-9]+)-folder/)|(folder/([0-9]+)-)) /folder [L,R=301]
```